# Extract files to Mounted SD Card fails

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, permissions, sd-card

I just got a UDOO QUAD board and I'm trying to put an ARCHLINUX on it. To do that, I found this [tutorial](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/freescale/udoo) online (check instalation section). However, I got stuck on step 6, I already downloaded ArchLinux, but when I try to extract the file to the mounted partition, as it says in the tutorial with: `bsdtar -xpf ArchLinuxARM-armv7-latest.tar.gz -C mnt`. I got lots of these errors:

```
./usr/share/file/misc/: Can't create 'usr/share/file/misc'
```

and eventually, the extraction fails. So I also tried to achieve the same result with tar:
`tar -xzvf ArchLinuxARM-armv7-latest.tar.gz -C mnt/`.
But I simply got a different set of errors, something like:

```
tar: ./usr/bin/groups: Cannot open: No such file or directory
./usr/bin/krb5kdc
tar: ./usr: Cannot mkdir: Input/output error
```

So I tried to search online, and I found some people with similar problems stating that this is a permission error, in other words, the compressed file doesn't have permission to write on the mounted partition. So I applied `ls -l`, and get as a result:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root      302981752 Dez 13 01:58 ArchLinuxARM-armv7-latest.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 16 root      root           4096 Dez 24 17:31 mnt
```

Clearly the files have different permissions, so this might be the problem, but I tried to chmod them with many different codes and to create them with root permissions to try to achive the same permission, and I didn't manage to achive the same permissions on both files.

SO that's basically it, if someone can help me out, please let me know.

Best Regards, Ernani

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS :D

Comment: The instructions assume you're also using (desktop) Archlinux, not Debian/Ubuntu, to extract and write to SD.

Comment: Hey @CelticWarrior thanks for the reply. I couldn't find a place that is saying that. But even if it's for ArchLinux Desktops, why exctract to a mounted partition wouldnt work on Ubuntu?